# Cannot reload Datatables server data

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to reload the ajax data into my Datatables list.

The jQuery code in js file is the following ( semplified )

```
 "use strict";
 var KTDatatablesDataSourceAjaxServer = function() {

    var initTable1 = function() {
       var table = $('#kt_table_1');

       // begin first table
       table.DataTable({
           responsive: true,
           searchDelay: 500,
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           ajax: server_url,
       });
   };

   return {

       //main function to initiate the module
       init: function() {
           initTable1();
       },

   };

 }();

 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     KTDatatablesDataSourceAjaxServer.init();
 });
```

Usually, Datatable API provide the following code to reload the server data

```
table.ajax.reload(null,false);
```

But in my case the code above doesn't work...I get an error of table not defined.
Any hint to fix the issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line `var table = $('#kt_table_1');` you are declaring `table` as a reference to DOM object only, not DataTable. Remove this line and Change your table initialization as below:

```
var table = $('#kt_table_1').DataTable({
           responsive: true,
           searchDelay: 500,
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           ajax: server_url,
       });
```